# Getting JSON data member from class

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest

I have class generated from JSON like this :

```
[DataContract]
public class Issue
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string expand { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string self { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string key { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class search
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string expand { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int startAt { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int maxResults { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public int total { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public IList<Issue> issues { get; set; }
}
```

I want to access " id " and I'm trying to retrieve like this:

```
jiraIssues.IssueKey = item.issues.key ?? string.Empty;
```

**getting error "does not contain a definition for "key".** Please check assembly ref

The "item" i'm getting like below:

```
foreach (search item in issuesearched)
{
    JiraIssues jiraissues = new JiraIssues();
    SetIssueDetails(item, jiraissues, priorities, statuses, resolution, issuetypes);
}
```

Is there any other way to access "key" ? Any suggession, where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I think we need to see how `issues` declared. Is it a list, single field/property? If it's a list, you have to specify index or key.

Comment: a class generated from `JSON` with `DataContract` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issues is a list
so you must do :

s.issues[0].key;

(if you want to set the key for the first element.
does not set key for other elements ;)

additional sample :

```
public class Issue
{                          
    public string key { get; set; }
}


public class search
{
    public IList<Issue> issues { get; set; }
}

private static void Main(string[] args) {

    search s = new search();

    s.issues.Add(new Issue()); // YOU HAVE THREE ISSUES
    s.issues.Add(new Issue());
    s.issues.Add(new Issue());


    var x=s.issues[0].key; // YOU ACCESS 1st one
    x = s.issues[2].key; // YOU ACCESS 3rd one (zero based)


}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not get. in my code for key, order is 3, so should I do, s.issues[3].key; ?

Comment: no. you have n issues. you need the index of the issue you want to set. that has nothing to do with the order.